# Is it possible to create SQL always on configuration in Windows 2016 cluster with no LB ip?

Tags: azure, windows-server-2016, alwayson, windows-clustering

don´t know if this possible or not.
client wants to create a Windows 2016 cluster with 2 different vms/nodes that are in Azure which are in different subscriptions and virtual networks. No shared storage

the idea is to configure SQL always on between them so that DB and sql config replicates exactly from VM1 to VM2. Then always on config would be removed when this syncs completes. client won´t do a normal backup/restore from one to the other (I already suggest them this aproach), they would go with always on aproach.

Vms are already on the same localdomain and they can ping each other . Command in powershell to test if cluster can be done with both vms was successfull:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Test-Cluster -Node VM07.domain.local,VM04.domain.local
WARNING: System Configuration - Validate Software Update Levels: The test reported some warnings..
WARNING: Network - Validate Network Communication: The test reported some warnings..
WARNING:
Test Result:
HadUnselectedTests, ClusterConditionallyApproved
Testing has completed for the tests you selected. You should review the warnings in the Report.  A cluster solu
supported by Microsoft only if you run all cluster validation tests, and all tests succeed (with or without war
Test report file path: C:\xxxx\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\Validation Report 2021.03.26 At 11.13.54.htm
```

Thing is that this cluster  doesn´t have a listener or load balancer IP, as this requires vms on same subnet . Cluster is only going to be used for SQL always on config.

Is it possible to create this cluster without a Loadbalancer Static IP for the cluster name?. Can the IP of one of the 2 nodes be used for this instead. something like:

***VM07 IP: 10.1.2.3
VM04 IP: 10.1.2.4***

```
New-Cluster –Name newcluster -Node VM07,VM04 –StaticAddress ClusterIP 10.1.2.3
–NoStorage
```

I know is a odd idea but want to be sure if it´s possible or not in practice.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use a single NIC per server (cluster node) and a single subnet.

Because the virtual IP access point works differently in Azure, you need to configure Azure Load Balancer to route traffic to the IP address of the FCI nodes or the availability group listener. In Azure virtual machines, a load balancer holds the IP address for the VNN that the clustered SQL Server resources rely on. The load balancer distributes inbound flows that arrive at the front end, and then routes that traffic to the instances defined by the back-end pool. You configure traffic flow by using load-balancing rules and health probes. With SQL Server FCI, the back-end pool instances are the Azure virtual machines running SQL Server.

Refer to this link for best practices and limitations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/hadr-cluster-best-practices

**UPDATE**

Azure Load Balancer or App Gateway can be configured with any kind of static or dynamic IP for destination.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/manage

Comment: So the answer would be no I guess...the aproach of clustering without LB ip, and using instead one of the nodes is not possible. The ai of clustering here is just of always on between 2 nodes and not the hole cluster idea.

Comment: Don't think so, you can use destination static IP's with and Azure load balancer.

Comment: yes but you can´t use a LB in Azure if vms are in different virtual networks as this case. Vnets are paired but LB need to have both in same subnet

Comment: Yes I already used an App gateway in different other scenarios, but thought that for creating a cluster you needed unexceptionally a internal load balancer.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configure-application-gateway-with-private-frontend-ip